# Relate a Notes table to multiple Entity tables using Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4, database-schema

I’m after some advice on database/entity design (I’m using the model designer for Entity Framework 4).

I have a number of entities (`Entity_1`, `Entity_2`, `Entity_3` …  `Entity_n`) I’d like to be able to attach notes to each entity where each record in `Entity_1` can have 0 or multiple notes, like wise for `Entity_2` etc.

After some Googling and messing around I’ve come up with the following, but I’m getting my `0—1’s`,`1-1’s` and `*-*’s` all confused now and could do with a reality check :) so I’d like to know Stack Overflows suggestions on the best way to architect this scenario for maintainability and ease of programing against.

I found two SO questions that are related, but opinions seem divided. I’d also like to get opinions in the context of using EF4 once the database is created.

- [Associating notes with different entities in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738344/associating-notes-with-different-entities-in-a-database)
- [Best way to implement a Notes Table for many entities Tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584517/best-way-to-implement-a-notes-table-for-many-entities-tables-in-sql)

### Option 1

[image: Option 1]

### Option 2

[image]

### Option 3

Every record has a globally unique Id and that Id links to a Note.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Long time from the post, but interested in hearing which approach did you end up taking, and what was the outcome?

Comment: The same here - Any outcome?

Answer (score 1):

From a data modelling perspective, you need an entity-notes link table for each of your entity tables (I know these may not actually be tables, but you have used up the "entity" word :)).

The modelling from there gets pretty easy.

Each of the link entities refers to the single notes table.

EF4 will abstract away many to many relationships for simple link tables (without a shared notes table), but I suspect it is easier to model the links explicitly in your case.

This also will allow you to add "payload" to the links i.e. extra information that relates to the link itself.